# run every monday at 5am

Tags: cron

I generated a cron to run every Monday at 5am.

```
0   5   1   *   1
```

The third number, 1, for day of month, has it set to run on the first of every month as well as Monday.

Do I change that 1 to 0 so it ignores the day of month? Otherwise it will run every Monday as well as run on the 1st of the month.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Have two entries:

to run every Monday at 5 AM : `0 5 * * 1`

to run on 1st of every month at 5 AM : `0 5 1 * *`

OR, if you want a single entry, the you may have to do something like: https://github.com/xr09/cron-last-sunday/blob/master/run-if-today

Comment: Is it always understood that `1` is Monday? Someplaces Sunday is last day of the week and not the first.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid day confusion we can give like this as well -

to run every Monday at 5 AM  :   `0 5 * * MON`